# Migrating: Kohana .htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm not a developer. I'm helping a friend to use a instance server at Amazon (Ubuntu) and I need a help to convert the .htaccess to nginx configs. I tried any sites that  promise the automatic convertion, but without success. Can You help me in this case, please?

This is the .htaccess:

```
        #http://# Turn on URL rewriting
        RewriteEngine On

        # Installation directory
        RewriteBase /

        # Protect hidden files from being viewed
        <Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
        </Files>

        # Protect application and system files from being viewed
        RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

        # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site.dev *.site.dev;
    root /var/www/site/public_html/;


    location / {
        expires off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @kohana;
    }

    # Prevent access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location @kohana {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php$request_uri last;
    }

    location ~* \.php {
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV development;
        fastcgi_cache off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/primalskill/kohana-nginx-config